# Activity throws this error: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

Tags: android

My code is here:

```
public class Water_schedule extends Activity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
          .detectDiskReads().detectDiskWrites().detectNetwork() // StrictMode is most commonly used to catch accidental disk or network access on the application's main thread
          .penaltyLog().build());

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_water_schedule);
        area = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
         submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsch);
            tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textSch);
            submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


                         new Access_water().execute();
                     }
            });
    }


    class Access_water extends AsyncTask<String , string ,string>{


        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Water_schedule.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

                @Override
                protected string doInBackground(String... arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                      ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                      // define the parameter
                      postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("area",
                  area.getSelectedItem().toString()));
                      String response = null;

                      // call executeHttpPost method passing necessary parameters 
                      try {
                 response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost(

                   "http://pcmc.site11.com/water.php", 
                   postParameters);

                 // store the result returned by PHP script that runs MySQL query
                 String result = response.toString();  

                  //parse json datasss
                     try{
                             returnString = "";
                       JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                             for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                                     JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                     Log.i("log_tag","area: "+json_data.getString("area")+
                                             ",timing: "+json_data.getString("timing")+
                                              ",event: "+json_data.getString("event")+
                                             ",day: "+json_data.getString("day")


                                     );
                                     //Get an output to the screen
                                     returnString += "\nArea : " + json_data.getString("area") +
                                             "\n____________________________\n Time : "+ json_data.getString("timing") + 
                                             "\n____________________________\nEvent : "+ json_data.getString("event")+
                                             "\n____________________________\nDay : "+ json_data.getString("day");
                             }
                     }
                     catch(JSONException e){
                             Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
                     }

                     try{
                      tv.setText(returnString);
                     }
                     catch(Exception e){
                      Log.e("log_tag","Error in Display!" + e.toString());;          
                     }   
                }
                      catch (Exception e) {
                 Log.e("log_tag","Error in http connection!!" + e.toString());     
                }

                    return null;
                }
                 @Override
                  protected void onPostExecute(string result) {   
                   super.onPostExecute(result);
                   pDialog.dismiss();
                 }

            }





}
```

I am trying to use a progress dialog while fetching data from a data base. The data base code also given above.

Please let me know what should I do to solve this error.

The same code is running on another activity without error.

Tell me how to use this progress dialog in more than one activity.

Comment: First off, you need to format your code properly. It's really difficult to read when written like this. I will also answer the question, check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You need to post more detail about your activities (are they declared as single instance, single task, single top or normal/default), for example.. when creating a singleTop or singleTask activity from outside of activity context, you need to set up a system / JVM task for the activity to run in. Android does that automatically for you when first invoking your activity, but you have to manually add a flag to the activity intent which launches it for subsequent or other activity launchers.

Apart from that, if you create a View on one activity, and you go into another task, and make another UI thread which also tries to access the same View (which was created on another UI thread), you will get an exception like this one you posted.

More common issue that Android beginners experience is accessing UI elements from a background thread, but I don't think it is the case here if you have the same code running correctly in another activity.

So basically, check your activity declaration, intent flags, and instantiate dialogs again while in other activities (or contexts). Hope this helps.

Android threading: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html